# Emberjs go back on cancel

Tags: ember.js

I have a link to User displayed from various screens(From User List, User Groups etc.). When the link is clicked, User is presented to edit. When cancel button is pressed in the edit form, I would like to transition to previous screen userlist/group. How is this generally achieved in Emberjs.

Thanks,
Murali

Comment: You can set a variable in the userController whose value depends on where you are coming from to the User route. In the action associated with cancel button,you can use the variable's value to decide which route to transition back to. You can use transitionToRoute to go back to the older route. Does this make sense?

Comment: It will be easier to explain if you have a JSFiddle with the code.

Comment: Your approach makes sense. I thought there could be a easier way. It just have to replicate back button behaviour. I don't have a JSFiddle, I will try create one

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need nothing more than

```
history.back()
```

One of the main design objectives of Ember, and indeed most OPA frameworks, is to work harmoniously with the browser's history stack so that `back` "just works".

So you don't need to maintain your own mini-history stack, or global variables, or  transition hooks.

You can put a `back` action in your application router to which actions will bubble up from everywhere, so you can simply say `{{action 'back'}}` in any template with no further ado.

Comment: The approach I proposed felt kinda half-baked to me as well, so if @torazaburo approach works - roll with it. :)

Comment: @Kalman I've seen several variants on your approach, so you're in august company. However, I've never seen a case where it was really necessary, notwithstanding the protests of the product/feature people that they "know" the user "really" wants to go back to magic place A. On the other hand, I have seen more than one case where poor schlobs ending up maintaining a half-baked roll-your-own history mechanism until they wised up and quit.

Comment: `<a href="#" {{action 'back'}} class="active ember-view">Back</a>` does it quite nicely.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I also heard this about AngularJS. Would you happen to have a source ?

Comment: Except `history.back()` could navigate you away from the app in cases where you opened a new tab or manually navigated to the edit url and the history stack isn't deep enough to your favor. The only way to handle this properly is on the application level, so my vote goes to @bdombro's answer, with the possible enhancement to specify a per-case "back" route (before defaulting to `/dash`) when `transitionHistory` is empty.

Comment: this will also likely bite you, when you decide to add acceptance tests.

Answer (score 4):

Here's my solution, which is very simple and high performance.

```js
// file:app/routers/application.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  transitionHistory: [],
  transitioningToBack: false,

  actions: {
    // Note that an action, like 'back', may be called from any child!  Like back below, for example.

    willTransition: function(transition) {
      if (!this.get('transitioningToBack')) {
        this.get('transitionHistory').push(window.location.pathname);
      }
      this.set('transitioningToBack', false);
    },
    
    back: function() {
      var last = this.get('transitionHistory').pop();
      last = last ? last : '/dash';
      this.set('transitioningToBack', true);
      this.transitionTo(last);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: As mentioned in comment in the other answer, this approach may be viable in some cases. Just note the implementation has following limitations:  
1. queryParams are dropped (can be retrieved from the willTransition(transition) parameter); 
2. route path from location.pathname contains slashes instead of dots, this may be an issue with query params again;
3. willTransition will not be called if your child routes consume the event and don't return true to allow bubbling. This can all be fixed with some minor adjustments to the code.

Answer (score 2):

There is probably a way to DRY(don't repeat yourself) this up, but one way of doing it is to have 2 actions: `willTransition` which Ember already gives you and `goBack` which you define yourself. Then, there is a "global" `lastRoute` variable that you keep track of as follows:

```
App.OneRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    willTransition: function(transition){
      this.controllerFor('application').set('lastRoute', 'one');
    },
    goBack: function(){
      var appController = this.controllerFor('application');
      this.transitionTo(appController.get('lastRoute'));
    }
  }
});
```

And your template would look as follows:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id='one'>
  <h2>One</h2>
  <div><a href='#' {{ action 'goBack' }}>Back</a></div>
</script>
```

Working example [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ciwime/1/edit?html,js,output)